# Running ng2 tour demo

Tags: angular, npm, bootstrap-tour

What are the necessary steps to get the tour demo to work after downloading the source code? I've tried multiple times but it gives me these errors after using the command **ng serve**:

ERROR in C:/Users/jimmy/angularpractice/ngx-tour-master/src/app/console/console.component.ts (1,29): Cannot find module 'ngx-tour-console'.

ERROR in C:/Users/jimmy/angularpractice/ngx-tour-master/src/app/console/console.module.ts (4,35): Cannot find module 'ngx-tour-console'.

ERROR in C:/Users/jimmy/angularpractice/ngx-tour-master/src/app/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.component.ts (1,29): Cannot find module 'ngx-tour-ng-bootstrap'.

ERROR in C:/Users/jimmy/angularpractice/ngx-tour-master/src/app/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.module.ts (4,39): Cannot find module 'ngx-tour-ng-bootstrap'.

ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve ngx-tour-ng-bootstrap relative to C:/Users/jimmy/angularpractice/ngx-tour-master/src/app/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.module.ts., resolving symbol NgBootstrapModule in C:/Users/jimmy/angularpractice/ngx-tour-master/src/app/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.module.ts, resolving symbol NgBootstrapModule in C:/Users/jimmy/angularpractice/ngx-tour-master/src/app/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.module.ts, resolving symbol NgBootstrapModule in C:/Users/jimmy/angularpractice/ngx-tour-master/src/app/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.module.ts
webpack: Failed to compile.

The source code for the ng2+ tour demo by using angular 2+ is here:

https://isaacplmann.github.io/ngx-tour/
https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-tour

Comment: Since this appears to be very specific to this one github repo, you may get a better answer by posting an issue to the github: https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-tour/issues

Comment: I'll give that a whirl. Thank you!